How to set xlim when save some frames to file by matplotlib in python?
I use python and matplotlib to create bar chart race animation, the data is time series and keep update every day. I want only save updated frames to file, for example, the frames are 10460 unti yesterday, the video file created in one hour.

The new 10 frames are appended today, I used code to save the newest frames to file as below, but axis a is too short, how can I set axis x to the same as max x in past?
anim = FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.anim_func, frames[10460:], init_func, interval=interval)


